# Is the element draggable ? Capybara

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara, draggable

I'm developping my application with Rails.

So, my question is quite simple and though, I haven't find any answer on the Internet.

I have some div with class="draggable" on my view.

I applied to all the element having this class the method .draggable(); found here :

http://jqueryui.com/draggable/

Then, in my capybara test, I want to check if all of the ".draggable" element really are draggable or not.

And I don't know what to use to verify if they're actually draggable or not.

With the chrome jquery console, I noticed that when I run ('.draggable').data(), there a uiDraggable object.

Anyways, I don't know how to write my test. If someone has an idea....?

thank you

Comment: Take a look to `drag_to` method. Not sure but maybe it will help: http://rubydoc.info/gems/capybara/frames

Comment: Well I've already looked at it but nothing helped me so far